# How can an electron behave as a wave and particles at the same time?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

Why do teachers take these kind of questions forgranted? Usually when i ask someone this question the answer is not satisfactory

Comment: [See also this list of related questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wave%20particle%20duality%20is%3aquestion)

Comment: Voting to close, because we can only speculate why teachers take certain questions for granted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because zero effort

Comment: First learn their teaching and next you will understand ... At least you will learn how to express questions and search answers in the books.

Comment: I don't know if you are still at high school but never forget that anything is forgranted in physics. If you search wave particle on this site, you will find a lot of references to experiments, well described in books and well introduced in wikipedia